# Adding annotation programatically in QGIS 3.10

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, annotation

I'm able to add an annotation in QGIS 3.10 it works with this code

```py
from qgis.core import QgsTextAnnotation, QgsPointXY, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsAnnotationManager
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvasAnnotationItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSizeF,QPoint

annot = QgsTextAnnotation()
annot.setFrameSize(QSizeF(100, 50))
annot.setMapLayer(layer)
annot.setFrameOffsetFromReferencePoint(QPoint(10, 10))
annot.setDocument(QTextDocument('TEST'))

# X and Y are defined previously
annot.setMapPositionCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(layer.crs()))
annot.setMapPosition(QgsPointXY(x, y))

QgsMapCanvasAnnotationItem(annot, qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas())
```

The annotation is added but I can't modify it in the GUI or delete it. How can I do it? There is an other thing to add in my code?

Comment: The code seems fine. Did you activate the "Annotation" tool (from the "Attributes" toolbar) before trying to edit the annotation in the GUI?

Comment: Yes i did. I can get the form to edit but when i push the ok button, the modification is not applied

Comment: I believe you should use the [QgsAnnotationManager](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Annotation/QgsAnnotationManager.html) for keeping track of the annotations. Can you try replacing your last line with `QgsProject.instance().annotationManager().addAnnotation(annot)`

Comment: Thanks @Jake it works great ! That was the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the annotation to the canvas, you should use the [QgsAnnotationManager](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Annotation/QgsAnnotationManager.html).

In your case, you could replace the last line of your code with

```py
QgsProject.instance().annotationManager().addAnnotation(annot)
```