# Exporting map to image with annotations created using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, annotation

Using QGIS 3.16, I have been able to create annotations following [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354935/adding-annotation-programatically-in-qgis-3-10). The problem is when saving the map as an image, the annotation will not render. Here are the portions of my code that create the annotation and save the image:

```py
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

Layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer1')

# MAP SETTINGS
img = QImage(QSize(715, 850), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
color = QColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
img.fill(color.rgba())
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
ms = QgsMapSettings()
ms.setBackgroundColor(color)
ext = Layer1[0].extent()
ms.setExtent(ext)

# TITLE ANNOTATION
title = QgsTextAnnotation()
title.setFrameSize(QSizeF(100, 25))
title.setFrameOffsetFromReferencePoint(QPoint(0, 0))
title.setDocument(QTextDocument('TEST'))
title.setMapLayer(Layer1[0])
title.setMapPositionCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(Layer1[0].crs()))
title.setMapPosition(QgsPointXY(ext.xMinimum(), ext.yMaximum()))
tsymb = QgsMarkerSymbol()
tsymb.setSize(0);
title.setMarkerSymbol(tsymb)
QgsProject.instance().annotationManager().addAnnotation(title)

# OUTPUT
ms.setLayers([Layer1[0]])
ms.setOutputSize(img.size())
render = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(ms, p)
render.start()
render.waitForFinished()
p.end()
img.save('C:/Users/user1/Desktop/test.jpeg')
```

What am I missing? It is odd that the annotation does appear in the map (canvas) when created via pyqgis and even when comparing it to one created using the GUI 'Text Annotation' they look exactly the same, but when exporting the map as a jpeg (using the GUI 'export map to image' option), only the one created with the GUI is rendered.